# Reason for the application crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

i currently have an application that calls webservice and stores data in core data,but when i terminate the application totally i.e even in the background then when i call the web service it crashes,what can be the problem?
here is the crash log from the device
can anyone help me out?

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb90f04 semaphore_wait_trap + 8

1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babc540 _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$up + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac87a0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 92
3   Eventz                          0x000f0a0c 0x82000 + 453132
4   Eventz                          0x000f3bac 0x82000 + 465836
5   Eventz                          0x000f3d14 0x82000 + 466196
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3baba4b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babb836 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up + 34
8   Eventz                          0x000f3ce2 0x82000 + 466146
9   Eventz                          0x000eff4c 0x82000 + 450380
10  Eventz                          0x000ecbae 0x82000 + 437166
11  Eventz                          0x000a37b4 0x82000 + 137140
12  Eventz                          0x00085492 0x82000 + 13458
13  Eventz                          0x00084f66 0x82000 + 12134
14  Eventz                          0x000ef5bc 0x82000 + 447932
15  Eventz                          0x000ee694 0x82000 + 444052
16  Eventz                          0x000ecc0a 0x82000 + 437258
17  Eventz                          0x000eccfc 0x82000 + 437500
18  Eventz                          0x00084b9a 0x82000 + 11162
19  UIKit                           0x359fdb2e -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:] + 270
20  UIKit                           0x359d687c -[UIApplication _callApplicationResumeHandlersForURL:payload:] + 100
21  UIKit                           0x359d5f66 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 1222
22  UIKit                           0x3582dd54 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1288
23  UIKit                           0x3582d6c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
24  UIKit                           0x3582d116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
25  GraphicsServices                0x3751f5a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
26  CoreFoundation                  0x339fa680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
27  CoreFoundation                  0x339f9ee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
28  CoreFoundation                  0x339f8cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
29  CoreFoundation                  0x3396beb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3396bd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
31  GraphicsServices                0x3751e2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
32  UIKit                           0x358812fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
33  Eventz                          0x00083d78 0x82000 + 7544
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x3badab1c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb91648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3baca4ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babcdf4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb90f04 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babc540 _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$up + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac87a0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 92
3   Eventz                          0x00089a26 0x82000 + 31270
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babb11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac9254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac93b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baefa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baef8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb90eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb91048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x339fa040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x339f8d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3396beb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3396bd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x39959500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3bafa30e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3bafa1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb90eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb91048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x339fa040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x339f8d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3396beb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3396bd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x342b83d0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x3433be80 __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3bafa30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3bafa1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb90f04 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babc540 _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$up + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac87a0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 92
3   Eventz                          0x000890ee 0x82000 + 28910
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babb11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac9254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac93b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baefa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baef8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb90f04 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babc540 _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$up + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac87a0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 92
3   Eventz                          0x00089a26 0x82000 + 31270
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x3babb11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac9254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac93b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baefa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baef8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bba10fc __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baea124 pthread_mutex_lock + 388
2   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b222544 umtx_lock + 60
3   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b283b74 0x3b221000 + 404340
4   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b28426c 0x3b221000 + 406124
5   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b222f0c ures_getByKeyWithFallback + 412
6   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b2c3b72 0x3b221000 + 666482
7   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b29e2b6 icu::Calendar::setWeekData(icu::Locale const&, char const*, UErrorCode&) + 294
8   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22b8ca icu::Calendar::Calendar(icu::TimeZone*, icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 106
9   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22b7f6 icu::GregorianCalendar::GregorianCalendar(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 22
10  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22b7d6 icu::GregorianCalendar::GregorianCalendar(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 6
11  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22af20 icu::Calendar::createInstance(icu::TimeZone*, icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 424
12  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b229a02 icu::SimpleDateFormat::initializeCalendar(icu::TimeZone*, icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 30
13  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22d416 icu::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 122
14  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22d392 icu::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 6
15  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b229594 icu::DateFormat::create(icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::Locale const&) + 156
16  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b229418 udat_open + 136
17  CoreFoundation                  0x339e878e __ResetUDateFormat + 342
18  CoreFoundation                  0x339ad988 CFDateFormatterCreate + 176
19  Foundation                      0x342b5072 -[NSDateFormatter _regenerateFormatter] + 254
20  Foundation                      0x342b4f08 -[NSDateFormatter stringForObjectValue:] + 108
21  Eventz                          0x000ca292 0x82000 + 295570
22  Eventz                          0x00089d16 0x82000 + 32022
23  Eventz                          0x000890a6 0x82000 + 28838
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x3babb11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac9254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac93b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baefa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
28  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baef8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bba10fc __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baea124 pthread_mutex_lock + 388
2   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b222544 umtx_lock + 60
3   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b284b44 0x3b221000 + 408388
4   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b2839e4 0x3b221000 + 403940
5   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b2cfd56 icu::NumberingSystem::createInstanceByName(char const*, UErrorCode&) + 162
6   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b2cfb94 icu::NumberingSystem::createInstance(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 152
7   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b224ed8 icu::DecimalFormat::construct(UErrorCode&, UParseError&, icu::UnicodeString const*, icu::DecimalFormatSymbols*) + 160
8   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b2af35c icu::DecimalFormat::DecimalFormat(icu::UnicodeString const&, icu::DecimalFormatSymbols*, UNumberFormatStyle, UErrorCode&) + 180
9   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b2af29e icu::DecimalFormat::DecimalFormat(icu::UnicodeString const&, icu::DecimalFormatSymbols*, UNumberFormatStyle, UErrorCode&) + 18
10  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b2cf7e6 icu::NumberFormat::makeInstance(icu::Locale const&, UNumberFormatStyle, UErrorCode&) + 1554
11  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22ce74 icu::SimpleDateFormat::initialize(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 20
12  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22d470 icu::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 212
13  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b22d392 icu::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 6
14  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b229594 icu::DateFormat::create(icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::Locale const&) + 156
15  libicucore.A.dylib              0x3b229418 udat_open + 136
16  CoreFoundation                  0x339e878e __ResetUDateFormat + 342
17  CoreFoundation                  0x339ad988 CFDateFormatterCreate + 176
18  Foundation                      0x342b5072 -[NSDateFormatter _regenerateFormatter] + 254
19  Foundation                      0x342b4f08 -[NSDateFormatter stringForObjectValue:] + 108
20  Eventz                          0x000ca292 0x82000 + 295570
21  Eventz                          0x00089d16 0x82000 + 32022
22  Eventz                          0x000890a6 0x82000 + 28838
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x3babb11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac9254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x3bac93b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
26  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baefa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baef8a0 start_wqthread + 4



Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash. Once you do you will see where it crashed more accurately. If you don't know how to do that, take a look at this great post http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: @frowing thanks for the article but something makes me feel that the application is being killed because it is taking long time to respond,do you know how to solve that issue?

Comment: @frowing com.***.*** failed to resume in time

Comment: Is that reason shown in the crash report? Usually when the app is being killed, you won't get a detailed crash report for all active threads! The crash reason is shown above the thread info in the crah report. You should add that info and of course symbolicate it as @frowing explained.

Comment: Is it possible that the call to webservice and/or the operation to save to core data is ongoing, while the app is going to background? If it is, both operations should be cancelled/suspended when the app goes to the background.

Answer (score 4):

failed to resume in time - means you are over loading the main thread. The application went background and when resumes the main thread should resume within 5-10 seconds, if not the application crashes. Check whether you are calling your web services from the main thread.